# Создание потока занимает слишком много времени

Tags: c++, многопоточность, visual-c++

Загружаю растровые тайлы асинхронно, каждый в своем потоке. Но заметил что сильно тормозит UI.
Замерил время, оказалось что создание одного потока занимает от 0.5 до 5 миллисекунд.
Начал гуглить, везде пишут что потоки стартуют довольно быстро, в бенчмарках у людей несколько микросекунд на создание одного потока, а у меня тысячи.
Я что-то делаю неправильно или это особенность Visual C++?
Одновременно запускаю не более 80 потоков.

```
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::thread(&RequestHandler::_request, this, host, port, body).detach();
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "[ms]" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds> (end - begin).count() << "[mic]" << std::endl;
```

Результат:

```
Time difference = 4[ms]
Time difference = 4350[mic]
Time difference = 0[ms]
Time difference = 701[mic]
Time difference = 0[ms]
Time difference = 594[mic]
Time difference = 2[ms]
Time difference = 2205[mic]
```

Comment: Главное правило - не создавайте новые потоки на каждый чих, создавайте пул потоков один раз в начале работы программы, а потом переиспользуйте эти потоки для всех новых задач. Тогда время создания потока не будет иметь значения

Comment: Или так: не создавайте потоки руками, а используйте [стандартные параллельные алгоритмы](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag), или то же самое из TBB. Оно само организует пул нужного размеров.

Comment: Тест не меряет создание потока, он меряет вызов конструктора и вызов функции `detach()` (которая явно используется ненадлежащим образом).

Comment: как всегда в попытках сделать бенчмарк, люди меряют все что угодно, кроме того, что они хотели померять.